# Pandas pd.Series().var() function is giving different output when compared with calculating std manually. Any Idea what's happening wrong here?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, variance

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation manually instead of using the pandas.Series().std() method but getting difference in output. Please help.

**Manual Variance Calculation**

```
values = pd.read_csv('Values.csv')

mom_1 = pd.Series(values['col_name'].mean() - values['col_name'])

mom_2 = mom_1*mom_1

print(np.sqrt(np.sum(mom_2.values,dtype = np.float64)/ values.shape[0] - 1))
```

**Output 1 - 10773.042044307498**

---

**Pandas Variance Calculation**

```
print(np.sqrt(pd.Series(values['col_name'].astype(np.float64)).var()))
```

**Output 2 - 10773.042044307516**

Tried replicating pandas nanvar function from pandas.core.nanops [pandas nanvar implementaton line 711](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.1/pandas/core/nanops.py) but still getting output 1 only. [find the Values.csv here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dtD-BfMOzohiDRkdVGp4xNKxjLKW4n9t/view?usp=sharing)

pandas==1.0.1
numpy==1.17.0

Any Idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: Floating point numbers have finite precision, and you're running into the limits here. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Accuracy_problems

Comment: Hey got the issue, it's because of a library called bottleneck, which pandas use for the faster calculation. Since pandas is using it with the default settings, turning it off now results in the same output. But thanks really appreciate your effort

Comment: Consider posting this as an answer to your own question. It can then act as a reference for people experiencing the same issue.

Comment: You have the same result to more than 10 decimal places of precision. When would you ever require precision greater than this? What are you complaining about?

Comment: Learn Machine learning Decsion Tree Split Mechanism before commenting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of a library called bottleneck, which pandas use for the faster calculation. Since pandas is using it with the default settings, turning it off now results in the same output.

Comment: Curious what you're working on where 0.000000001% precision matters

Comment: Working on matching predictions generated from lgbm. Some of the columns in test set has value generated from pandas functions which now costing me time complexity over the deployment API. Trying to reduce it by using numpy and dynamic programming. These precision loss is affecting the trees split points hence prediction are not getting matched.

Comment: I'm not sure how you do your matching, but this could possibly be of use to you: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal.html